# Sidebar overlaps footer when scrolling down

Tags: bug, design, sidebar

I am not sure if this was previously reported (if so, please excuse me) or if it is even considered a bug, but i see what is shown in the image below when i go to "New Question" page in Stack Overflow and scroll down.

[image]

Comment: Yep, it seems to be the same. I didn't find it before. Thanks for pointing it out @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M

Comment: @Mindastic you can mark your own question as a duplicate.